# I'm currently working on a custom function that replicates the workings of the built-in "split" method

Tags: python

This is the string that should be split: **"Python    2     3"**
using **"split('Python    2     3', maxsplit=1)"**
and this is the expected result: **['Python', '2     3']**

For some reason, the code completely ignores the maxsplit argument.
(There are other test cases that will require modifications to the code, but for now this is the first case that the code cannot solve properly.)

What could be the issue?

```
def split(data: str, sep=None, maxsplit=-1):
    result = []
    start = 0
    count = 0

    #If sep is None, split based on whitespace
    if sep is None:
        parts = _split_whitespace(data)
        result.extend(parts)
        return result

    #Loop through the characters of the string
    for i, char in enumerate(data):
        #Check if the current character is the separator
        if char == sep:
            #Check if maxsplit has been reached
            if count == maxsplit:
                break
            #Append the substring from the start index to the current index
            result.append(data[start:i])
            start = i + 1  # Update the start index for the next substring

            #Increment the count of splits
            count += 1

    #Append the remaining substring (if any) to the result
    result.append(data[start:])

    return result

def _split_whitespace(data):
    parts = []
    start = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(data):
        if char.isspace():
            if start < i:
                parts.append(data[start:i])
            start = i + 1
    if start < len(data):
        parts.append(data[start:])
    return parts

print(split('Python    2     3',None, 1))
```

This code prints out: **['Python', '2', '3']**
When comparing the two results, the built-in method stops splitting after Python, but the custom function doesn't.

Comment: well, just glancing at your code, if you are splitting on whitespace, you dont' do anything with `maxsplit`, all the work is done in `_split_whitespace`

Comment: Thank you. So _split_whitespace overrides maxsplit. I'm gonna try to remove it then.

Comment: Or pass `maxsplit` as an argument to `_split_whitespace`. But indeed, no reason to have a helper function that mirrors the main one; `if sep is None: sep = " "` would be simpler.